# Google API User Messages. How do you get a list of messages by received date?

Tags: list, google-api, message

I have been searching online for a while now an am not sure why I haven't found an answer to this question.  Thanks in advance to anyone who has cracked this case.

I simply need to make a call to the user.messages.list api and get the most recent 5 messages in my gmail.  I have been able to get 5 messages no problem, but I don't know how to get them in chrono order.  The inbox could potentially be huge, so I can't imagine you have to get pages and then sort on the client side.

Anybody run into this?  So the list just returns, basically, a list of email Ids.  Then I have to make a call to get the emails themselves.  At least that is what I am having to do.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack.  With out knowing without knowing what language you are using or seeing your code no one can help you fix it.  please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will help you to create good well formed questions in the future

Comment: Huh, i thought that was pretty clear...I will rephrase and repost anew.